# Show a View on the top of existing showing view on tabbar button click rectnative

Tags: react-native

I have created a custom tabbar through which I can control the action performed by clicking tab buttons,

I want to disable a tab button so that it didn't render whole UI screen but instead of that want to show a custom popup on the top existing screen

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity , Alert} from "react-native";

const S = StyleSheet.create({
container: { flexDirection: "row", height: 52, elevation: 2 },
tabButton: { flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }


});



const TabBar = props => {


const {
renderIcon,
getLabelText,
activeTintColor,
inactiveTintColor,
onTabPress,
onTabLongPress,
getAccessibilityLabel,
navigation


} = props;

  const { routes, index: activeRouteIndex } = navigation.state;




showalert = () =>  {
  return (
      <View>
          <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </View>
  )


}
```

return (

{routes.map((route, routeIndex) => {
const isRouteActive = routeIndex === activeRouteIndex;
const tintColor = isRouteActive ? activeTintColor : inactiveTintColor;

```
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={routeIndex}
        style={S.tabButton}
        onPress={() => {
            (routeIndex == 2) ? alert(routeIndex) : onTabPress({ route });
        }}
        onLongPress={() => {
          onTabLongPress({ route });
        }}
        accessibilityLabel={getAccessibilityLabel({ route })}
      >
        {renderIcon({ route, focused: isRouteActive, tintColor })}

        <Text>{getLabelText({ route })}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  })}
</View>
```

);
};

export default TabBar;

Answer (score 0):

You can Give the view fixed position on top sp that it will place on top

```
tabButton: {
       position:absolute,top:0
    },
```

This will place the View on the top of the screen always.